# Unity/GNOME/GTK3 & Other Desktop Issues

Tags: 12.10, unity, gnome, drivers, nvidia

Well, it's been about a week, and i'm quite frustrated. I just recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my desktop, and i've run into more than a few problems along the way.

First, it began with having issues with installing the GRUB bootloaders on a dual boot system, which was fixed. Then, after getting it fully installed, and booting up to find out the nvidia drivers were botched (this, however after many attempts got fixed, was due to kernel images being mix matched with the current state of nvidia-current or something.). After all that, i had felt that Unity was still a bit sluggish, so i tweaked some of the settings using `ccsm`, and i ticked something i shouldn't have ticked (of course.. :/) thus making me unable to boot up fully and see the taskbar and panels, but only the icons.

I figured, at this point, i'd might as well try Gnome, after hearing about it allot. I installed Gnome Remix because i liked it better then gnome, and it worked for two days. After, changing my mind again, (not liking the panels in Gnome or Gnome classic), i wanted to fix Unity. after researching for a few minutes, i got Unity back up and running, after reboots even. Now, being 1h ago, after enabling the 'Unity Plugin" in `ccsm`, and rebooting, no matter what i use, Gnome, Gnome Classic, Unity, all i get is my background, no icons, no taskbar, and no panels or popups whatsoever.

I might also add, since the first install, i've gotten a crap-ton of "System Failed" or "Ubuntu 12.10" issues, which i've reported all i could.

Which leads me here, kinda desktop screwed, because i don't want to go back to windows, losing all my transferred items, re-installing due to the same reason, or even the fact that i have very slow internet, so anything over 100mb will take me more than a few hours to download.

So, is there any way to un-screw myself from this predicament? Oh and, i installed Ubuntu 12.10 using the same iso on my laptop, which is running flawlessly. (fml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a python script that it claims to reset Unity and Compiz settings back to default, it may could help you avoid reinstalling your desktop. You should be able to download it or install it through apt by adding the PPA to sources list.

Using terminal (you will have to provide administrator's [root] password)

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:amith/ubuntutools` this will add the PPA to sources
`sudo apt-get update` perform an update
`sudo apt-get install unity-reset` install it
`unity-reset` perform the reset.

References:
[Script's git repository](https://github.com/phanimahesh/unity-revamp)

[A blogpost mentioning the process](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Well, when using this tool, (it segfaulted though). Near the end, right before the segfault, it states that there was a compiz parsing error (GTK theme 'no such file or directory'). I'm going to see if i can reset compiz, again, and see if that works. EDIT: seems that i get different errors directly with dconf-tools, saying that '-f' is not a parameter. i'm still confused..

Comment: Welp, i'm not sure which one exactly fixed the issue, but i cleared out all profiles from my $home folder, and re-installed the whole ubuntu-desktop and it's dependencies. Lets hope it stays fixed.. :o